# Java - Enable Combo boxes depending on radio button

Tags: java, swing, combobox, radio-button

I'm trying to make taxi booking application. Now, if I (for example) want to schedule by mobile application, then I want to enable combobox with drivers name and if someone schedule via phone call, then I want to enable combobox with dispatchers names. How? I tryied something in `initActions()`, but, obvious it's not working...

```
public class OrderWindow extends JFrame {

    private JLabel lblCustomerName;
    private JTextField txtCustomerName;
    private JLabel lblDateOrder;
    private JPanel pnlDateOrder; 
    private JLabel lblDepartureAdress;
    private JTextField txtADepartureAdress`
    private JComboBox cbDriver;
    private JRadioButton rbMobileApp;
    private JRadioButton rbPhoneCall;
    private ButtonGroup bgOrder;

    public OrderWindow(){
        setTitle("Scheduling");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        initGUI();
        initActions();
    }



    private void initActions() {
        rbMobileApp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource()==rbMobileApp) {
                    setEnabled(rbMobilnaAplikacija.isSelected());
                } 
            }
        });
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        MigLayout mig = new MigLayout("wrap 2", "[][]", "[]10[][]10[]");
        setLayout(mig);
        lblCustomerName = new JLabel("Name and Lastname");
        txtCustomerName = new JTextField(20);

        lblDepartureAdress = new JLabel("Adress");
        txtDepartureAdress = new JTextField(20);

        rbMobileApp = new JRadioButton("Application");
        rbPhoneCall = new JRadioButton("Call");
        bgPorudzbina = new ButtonGroup();
        add(lblCustomerName);
        add(txtCustomerName);
        add(lblDepartureAdress);
        add(txtDepartureAdress);
        add(rbMobileApp);
        add(rbPhoneCall);
        bgOrder = new ButtonGroup();
        bgOrder.add(rbMobileApp);
        bgOrder.add(rbPhoneCall);   
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just 2 JRadioButtons and 2 JComboBoxes, then the solution is simple: Give the JRadioButtons an ItemListener that checks if the radio is selected, and if so, select the corresponding JComboBox.

e.g.,

```
radioBtn.addItemListener(evt -> {
    combo.setEnabled(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
});
```

If you have a bunch of JRadioButton / JComboBox combinations, then you need a more robust way to connect the two, and that can be achieved by either using a Map such as a HashMap, or by putting both objects into their own class, for example something like:

[image]

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class RadioCombo<T> {
    private JRadioButton radioBtn;
    private JComboBox<T> combo;

    public RadioCombo(String text, DefaultComboBoxModel<T> model) {
        radioBtn = new JRadioButton(text);
        combo = new JComboBox<>(model);
        combo.setEnabled(false);
        radioBtn.addItemListener(evt -> {
            combo.setEnabled(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
        });
    }

    public JRadioButton getRadioBtn() {
        return radioBtn;
    }

    public JComboBox<T> getCombo() {
        return combo;
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestRadioCombo extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] DATA = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    private static final String[] INNER_DATA = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
    private static final int GAP = 3;
    public TestRadioCombo() {
        ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        for (String datum : DATA) {

            DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
            for (String innerDatum : INNER_DATA) {
                String item = datum + " - " + innerDatum;
                model.addElement(item);
            }
            RadioCombo<String> radioCombo = new RadioCombo<>(datum, model);
            buttonGroup.add(radioCombo.getRadioBtn());
            addRadioCombo(radioCombo);
        }
    }

    private void addRadioCombo(RadioCombo<String> radioCombo) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, 2 * GAP);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        add(radioCombo.getRadioBtn(), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
        add(radioCombo.getCombo(), gbc);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TestRadioCombo());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Another option is to have a bunch of JRadioButtons and only **one** JComboBox, and then in your radio button item listener, swap the JComboBox's ***model*** depending on which JRadioButton was selected.